# Invoice Extraction

Tags: object-detection

What topics should I read on to prepare myself for data extraction from invoices (in image file or PDF). Basically I will have a file with invoice and need to extract from it such information as number, dates, lines and totals. I will probably use Python but not necessairly. I would appreciate any techinque/articles or event book recommendation. I want to do this task with understanding of what I am doing rather than simply running a library. I did read on Deep Learning in general (first few chapters of http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) but feel this problem is not exactly was this book is about.

One additional practical problem I have in mind is that abviusly I will need a lot of example invoices to train my model. In addition to authentic invocies which I can gather myself (say one hundred) could "fake" invoices work?

*PS. If this StackExchange site is not the best for this type of Deep Learning question, please could you recommend a better StackExchange site.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted information from pdf:s a few years ago and I used a bunch of different tools. The issue with reading data from pdfs is that you never quite know how the data will look like once you start extracting it. Therefore, you might need several different tools/approaches for extracting different parts of the document

Here are a few tips:

- I used [Xpdf](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) tools which are a set of command-line utilities for parsing PDF documents. This was helpful for extracting numerical values from tables in the pdfs.
- I also wrote **a lot** of long regular expressions for finding specific sections in the documents.
- I also used [maven](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2019/07/06/extracting-tables-from-pdf/) for extracting tabular data